# Wordpress Menu Items don't want to Center

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, center, nav

I have some menu items which just don't want to center no matter what I do. I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. I feel like it might be a problem with the PHP pulling the menu items (I don't know PHP, it's from a theme) because when I manually add in my own UL of menu items, they center perfectly.

Any help would be appreciated!

**PHP File Code**

```
<div id="hmenubar">

    <?php $navcheck = '' ; ?>

    <?php $navcheck = wp_nav_menu( array(   'container_class' => 'menu-header', 
                        'theme_location' => 'primary' , 
                        'menu_class' => 'nav', 
                        'fallback_cb' => '', 
                        'echo' => false ) ); ?>
    <?php  if ($navcheck == '') { ?>

        <ul class="nav">            

            <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&sort_column=menu_order'); ?>

        </ul>

    <?php } else echo($navcheck); ?>  

</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
#hmenu_container {
height: 30%;
width:100%;
display: block;
text-align; center;
}

#hmenubar {
margin: 0 auto; 
}

#hmenubar ul {
font-family: 'Calligraffitti', cursive;
font-size: 1.5rem;
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Edit: HTML of List**

```
<div class="menu-header">

<ul id="menu-photography" class="nav">

<li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-15"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13"><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20"><a href="/projects/">Projects</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-16"><a href="/insquares">Insquar.es</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-17"><a href="/instagram">Instagram</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Because I'm new I can't add images to my posts so here's imgur:
[Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/RPDOlpu.jpg)

Comment: can you post the html code of the menu that's outputted by wordpress?

Comment: I edited my original post to include the HTML

Comment: I'm assuming that the HTML is missing the closing `</ul>` and `</div>` in the menu is just a copy and paste mistake

Comment: oops, yes sorry it was. Fixed now. I feel retard.

Comment: What theme are you using, or do you have a link?

Answer (score 0):

```
#hmenu_container {
    height: 30%;
    width:100%;
}
#hmenubar {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}
#hmenubar ul {
    font-family:'Calligraffitti', cursive;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}
#hmenubar li {
    display: inline;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bryaW/)

Comment: Thanks for spotting that one. I fixed it, although it still hasn't centered:

    `#hmenu_container {
 height: 30%;
 width:100%;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
    }`

Comment: I've edited my answer, change `display:block` to `inline` in `#hmenu_container`

Comment: Thanks again, but it still hasn't centered. Here is the updated CSS:
  
 #hmenu_container {  
 height: 30%;  
 width:100%;  
 display: inline;  
 text-align: center;  
}  
  
#hmenubar {  
 margin: 0 auto;  
 
 
}  

#hmenubar ul {  
 font-family: 'Calligraffitti', cursive;  
 font-size: 1.5rem;  
 display: inline-block;  
 list-style: none;  
 margin: 0 auto;  
}  
  
#hmenubar li {  
 display: inline;  
}


p.s. how do I format code in comments. 'help' isn't very helpful

Comment: (If I could upvote you I would, but I can't because it's a new account). Thanks, but it's still not working :S I copied your code exactly. What else could it possibly be?

Comment: Well it works in JSFiddle, so I would check if there is other CSS overwriting something (e.g. if you take away all the css but what I posted - does it work?)

Comment: double check the css class names, make sure there is no spelling mistakes

Comment: lol even though I removed all other CSS it still aligned left...
That's why I feel like there's something weird happening in the theme's PHP. 

Thanks for all your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this very problem recently, and when I couldn't get that menu to center, I searched for help on Google, and found this page. Like you, I tried JSFiddle's answer, and it did not work, so I started to break down everything within this specific code. I did finally get the menu bar to center, when I noticed this part of the code:

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php $navcheck = wp_nav_menu( array(   'container_class' => 'menu-header', 
                    'theme_location' => 'primary' , 
                    'menu_class' => 'nav',
                    'fallback_cb' => '', 
                    'echo' => false ) ); ?>
```

Specifically:

```
                    'menu_class' => 'nav',
```

When I looked for **nav** in my CSS files, I found it located in a file named **superfish.css** in the theme I was editing. I noticed that this file contained essentially the same code twice, one labeled as a demo skin, with the code in question like this:

**CSS:**

```
/*** DEMO SKIN ***/
.nav {
float:  left;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

Easily enough, I changed the **float: left;** to **float: center;** and my menu bar centered.

I hope this helps anyone else who has this problem! :)

Comment: When I went to do this again from scratch, it didn't work. What I ultimately had to do (what I did do the first time, but forgot to mention it) was give the menu a fixed width, because when I made it 100%, it made the entire block 100% and tried to center the block. So, I had to make the block (in my case) 800px, then the center worked again. Sorry about that.